# DSC error: powershell async result could not be found in 20 seconds

Tags: powershell, enterprise, dsc

I'm using DSC to deploy software to multiple computers. On some of the computers an error occured:
powershell async result could not be found in 20 seconds.

Does anybody have any idea what could be the cause?

Problem happened only once.

Comment: You are having a timeout issue because a connection cannot be completed.  Are allow computers in the same network?   Are they in the same domain?